# Configuring ConnectionFactory for RabbitMQ in Spring Boot AMQP

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

**TL;DR** How to create Spring Boot AMQP connection factory programatically?

Hey,

In order to connect to my RabbitMQ I added these to my `application.properties` file of my Spring Boot app:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=host
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=myapp
spring.rabbitmq.password=mypass
```

And according to my understanding, these values are then used to create Spring Boot's auto configured `ConnectionFactory`, which I then use in:

```
@Bean
@Conditional(RabbitCondition.class)
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter completedOrderListenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(completedOrderQueueName);
    container.setMessageListener(completedOrderListenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
```

I would like to be able to use rabbitMQ credentials from different environment files which are not `application.properties`, so I would like to create `ConnectionFactory` bean programatically.
How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setAddresses(address);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Comment: what is `address`? In the properties we have host and port.

Comment: @tostao address = host